# Who will be our target audience when the site is launched?

Tags: discussion

Our work here of asking and answering questions goes way beyond our fun and is aimed to benefit people who are looking for learning more about the Portuguese language and clearing up any doubts of it.

My question is regarding scope. I think we should ask and answer questions if they are of any benefit for our target audience.

So, who will be our target audience and what they can learn when the site is launched?

Comment: Todas as pessoas com dúvidas sobre algum aspeto da língua, na minha opinião pertencem ao público alvo.

Comment: Concordo com o @someonewithpc.

Comment: Related, because the target audience should be a reason to (or not to) translate the interface: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/43/podemos-reaproveitar-as-tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-site-vindas-do-sopt

Answer (score 8):

I think our target audience of askers is:

- Basic users - learners;
- Expert users - fluent speakers trying to polish their language skills.

I think our target audience of answerers are:

- Native and fluent speakers;
- Scholars and language academics - hopefully.

Comment: Do you mean to include or exclude native speakers in fluent speakers?

Comment: Include! I would expect a French to be fluent in French. :)

Comment: -1 because of "Basic users". See @Sérgio's answer and my comments there.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the target audience should be from advanced users to expert users.

Personally, I can't see much reason to have basic users as the target audience, because there is plenty of information online aimed at beginners.

If we promote basic questions, we risk being a redundant source of information on portuguese language and keeping away more advanced learners (to ask questions) and experts (to answer).

I would suggest the lowest threshold to be advanced learners. These are the ones that find it harder to have their doubts answered from online resources and more likely to look for help from a trustworthy forum like ours.

This question is very important, because in answering it we are defining the motto of this website, i.e., its 'personality'.

Comment: That's a very good point and also a thing that might be hard to balance right in practice. For me the influx of low level users/questions was the single biggest reason that made me stop visiting my otherwise favorite site (WPSE) so often.

Comment: The question is - where and how to draw a line between the basic and intermediate/advanced users? One of the already present mechanisms should be the "prior research" imperative - if it is a basic question and user really makes an effort to research it beforehand he or she will probably be able to find the answer elsewhere and then eventually ask for a clarification here. Apart from that I am not sure how to judge whether the question is "too basic" or not.

Comment: Last but not least - let's not forget that many basic questions in the SO/SE network have inspired amazingly exhaustive and interesting answers.